# Check whether in specific columns all elements of rows are NA

Tags: r, apply, purrr

I want my_var to be 0 if my_var_a to my_var_c are all NA

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  my_var my_var_a my_var_b my_var_c my_var_others
   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>         <int>
1      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
2      1       NA        1       NA            NA
3      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
4     NA       NA       NA       NA            NA
```

I get my desired result using:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(my_var = if_else(apply(select(., my_var_a:my_var_c), 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), 0L, my_var))
```

Is there a less complicated way of doing that or at least a way using `purrr`? I looked into `pmap` but couldn't figure out how it would replace apply.

Which results in:

```
  my_var my_var_a my_var_b my_var_c my_var_others
   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>         <int>
1      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
2      1       NA        1       NA            NA
3      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
4      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
```

This is the data frame:

```
structure(list(my_var = c(0L, 1L, 0L, NA), my_var_a = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), my_var_b = c(NA, 1L, 
NA, NA), my_var_c = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), my_var_others = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmap_int` from `purrr` to iterate over multiple columns row-wise.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(my_var = pmap_int(select(., my_var_a:my_var_c), ~any(!is.na(c(...)))))

#  my_var my_var_a my_var_b my_var_c my_var_others
#   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>         <int>
#1      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
#2      1       NA        1       NA            NA
#3      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
#4      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
```

---

In base R, we can use `rowSums` and assign 1 to rows where there is atleast one non-NA value.

```
cols <- paste0("my_var_",letters[1:3])
df$my_var <- +(rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) < length(cols))
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for `all(is.na(x))` yields `TRUE` where you want `0`, so use `!` in front. The `^1` transforms into `"numeric"`. Fairly uncomplicated in base R.

```
dat <- transform(dat, my_var=apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))^1)
dat
#   my_var my_var_a my_var_b my_var_c my_var_others
# 1      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
# 2      1       NA        1       NA            NA
# 3      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
# 4      0       NA       NA       NA            NA
```